# AWS Lambda : Every time create new object even defined AddScoped

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am new in AWS lambda, I am trying to implement Dependency Injection
in lambda function as suggested by link https://garywoodfine.com/dependency-injection-in-aws-lambda/

After implement as per above link it works properly for the "AddTransient" type but not work for the "AddScoped" if I register interface and class as AddTransient, it return new GUID in each time when lambda function invoke with same lambda instance before it goes to down/kill.

While I register same interface and class as AddScoped, even though it return same previous GUID in each request (menas lambda function invoke) with same lambda instance before it goes to down/kill. I am expecting same GUID in same request but new GUID in different request.

It seems it work as singleton even registered as scope type.

Sample Code

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using AWSLambda1.UseCase;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace AWSLambda1
{
    public class Function
    {
        ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public Function()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<ITenantInfo, TenantInfo>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IService1, Service1>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IService2, Service2>();
        }
      
        public string FunctionHandler(object input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var tenantInfo= _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITenantInfo>();

            var service1 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService1>();
            var service2 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService2>();

            //Every time I got same GUID even I set "AddScoped"
            //on each time Lambda Trigger before it goes to kill.

            /* 
             
            First  Lambda Trigger at 5:45:40 : 
            ===================================

                Service 1 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e
                Service 2 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e

            Second Lambda Trigger at 5:45:45 : (Idealy, it should generate new GUID but it returns previous one)
             ===================================

                Service 1 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e
                Service 2 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e

            Third  Lambda Trigger at 5:45:50 : (Idealy, it should generate new GUID but it returns previous one)
            ===================================

                Service 1 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e
                Service 2 GUID ==> b15399ba-5dba-4d92-8c28-b9065d34ef8e

            Lambda function goes donw after 5 minutes and generate new GUID after it.
            
            Fourth  Lambda Trigger at 5:55:00 : (now, it generate new GUID)
            ===================================

                Service 1 GUID ==> 44edc8f0-0988-43a1-ac51-f4187f5aae04
                Service 2 GUID ==> 44edc8f0-0988-43a1-ac51-f4187f5aae04

            //My expection is it should be new in first, second and third time lambda function invoke
            //as I register class and interface by AddScoped method but it work as singleton.

            */
            LambdaLogger.Log("Service 1 GUID==>" + service1.GetTenantInfo().GUID); 
            LambdaLogger.Log(Environment.NewLine);

            LambdaLogger.Log("Service 2 GUID==>" + service2.GetTenantInfo().GUID);
            LambdaLogger.Log(Environment.NewLine);

            return "Done";
        }
    }
}
```